# Idiomatic J for value of item at index n of array x

Tags: j

In the J language, what is the *idiomatic* word or phrase to return the value of the item at index n of array x?
The documentation for {:: seems concerned with boxed values, mentioning normal arrays as an afterthought.

```
    nth =: {:: NB. This is what I have found, but is there a better word?
    2 nth 5 12 73 23 89
73
    1 nth 3 3 $ i.9
3 4 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for *from* (`{`). It returns item(s) from an array

```
   2 { 5 12 73 23 89
73
   2 4 { 5 12 73 23 89
73 89
   2 { i. 4 5
10 11 12 13 14
```

Some references for *from*:

- [Vocabulary on Jwiki](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/curlylf#dyadic)
- [J Dictionary](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help803/dictionary/d520.htm)

Comment: Thanks.  I wrongly thought that x{y meant "find index of value x in y".

Comment: For anyone wondering how I could be so mislead, its because the Lab "A J Introduction" Chapter 1 Page 13 uses 9?.9 as test data.

       p=:9 ?. 9    NB. A random permutation
       p
    0 5 8 3 4 1 7 6 2
       p { p
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

In this very unfortunate example, looking up indexes by each value gives the same result as looking up values by each index.